# How to subclass a class that has a __new__ and relies on the value of cls?

Tags: python

My specific use case is I'm trying to subclass `pathlib.Path`. I want to be able to add or override some functionality, but I also want to inherit all of Path. Path has a `__new__` and in it has:

```
if cls is Path:
    cls = WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else PosixPath
```

In other words, Path requires passing the proper class to it. The problem is I don't know how to both create MY class and call `Path.__new__` with `cls == Path`.

I've tried many things and each one gives me a different problem. 
This one gives me `AttributeError: type object 'RPath' has no attribute '_flavour'` because I'm trying to override the parent class.

Python3:

```
class RPath(Path):
    def __new__(cls, basedir, *args, **kwargs):
         return Path.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, basedir, *pathsegs):
        super().__init__()
        self.basedir = basedir

    def newfunction(self):
        print('Something new')
```

And this one gives returns a Path object, and hence doesn't allow me to do my overrides.

```
def __new__(cls, basedir, *args, **kwargs):
    return Path.__new__(Path, *args, **kwargs)
```

I also tried various usages of `super()`, to no avail.

This seems like it should be pretty easy. What am I missing?

Update: What am I trying to accomplish?
Specifically, I want to make `class RPath(basedir, *pathsegments)`:

```
rpath=RPath('\root\dir', 'relpath\path2\file.ext)
assert rpath.basedir == '\root\dir' # True
rpath.rebase('\new_basedir')
assert rpath.basedir === '\newbasedir' # True
# And while I'm at it
assert rpath.str == str(rpath)  # make str a property == __str__(self)
```

Comment: What is the exact functionality you want to insert in __new__?

Comment: You need to clarify what you're trying to do here. The functionality from `Path.__new__` you're trying to preserve will instantiate a *different class*, so if you did get that part of the code to run, your subclassing would go away.

Comment: Updated above. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.  And more specifically, pathlib doesn't call `__init__`. So somewhere I want to take the first argument `class RPath(baselib, *pathsegments)` and set `self.baselib = baselib` in `__new__` or in my own `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's going to be possible in the usual way.  But even if you could do it, it wouldn't work, because what Path is doing is not returning a plain Path either, it's returning some subclass (WindowsPath or PosixPath).  So your overrides to Path won't take effect, because if you were able to inherit `Path.__new__`, it would still return, say, a WindowsPath, and WindowsPath inherits from Path, not your custom path subclass.

It seems `pathlib.Path` has an idiosyncratic class structure, and you'll have to do some special work to duplicate it.  At a first guess, you would need to make your own subclasses of WindowsPath and PosixPath, and then make a Path subclass that delegates to instantiate one of those instead of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is *a* solution, though it doesn't use inheritance. I still suspect that there is a straight-up, simple inheritance way to do it (though see BrenBarn's response for the other side).

This method uses composition.  The key is using `__getattr__` and `getattr()` to automatically delegate all requests not found in the wrapper class to the wrapped class.  Here is an example:

```
class RPath(object):
    def __init__(self, basedir, *pathsegs):
        self.p = Path(*pathsegs)
        self.basedir = basedir

    # Override existing behavior
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) is RPath and self.basedir == other.basedir and self.p == other.p      

    # Add new behavior
    def cp(self):
        return self.basedir / self.p      

    # Everything not found here, automatically delegate to Path
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.cp, attr)
```

Comment: This class can not be corretly pickled/unpickled

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are under absolutely **no obligation** to actually call your superclass's `__new__` or `__init__`. The only constraint is that you ultimately call `object.__new__(cls)` in order to allocate an object of type `cls`.

So, simply copy the relevant logic out of your superclass's `__new__` into your own.